# Create a data frame from multiple data frames R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   798 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ READMIT.ENCOUNTER   : int  (intentionally blank)
 $ MRN                 : int  (intentionally blank)
 $ READMIT.SOURCE      : Factor w/ 5 levels "Emergency Unit",..: 5 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ READMIT.DATE        : Factor w/ 300 levels "1/1/2013","1/11/2013",..: 83 25 92 88 4 92 26 18 24 9 ...
 $ READMIT.DISC.DATE   : Factor w/ 284 levels "1/10/2013","1/11/2013",..: 10 8 22 22 14 26 3 25 1 112 ...
 $ READMIT.MONTH       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ READMIT.YEAR        : int  2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 ...
 $ LOS                 : int  11 10 4 7 11 8 4 4 3 18 ...
 $ INTERIM             : int  24 27 27 19 29 4 21 9 18 18 ...
 $ READMIT.INSURANCE   : Factor w/ 33 levels "A12","A13","B03",..: 1 2 1 23 9 4 19 2 2 2 ...
 $ READMIT.MDC         : Factor w/ 18 levels "CIRCULATORY DZ",..: 17 17 7 13 1 14 17 1 17 17 ...
 $ READMIT.DRG         : Factor w/ 141 levels "100","102","103",..: 19 19 65 127 41 80 18 42 20 21 ...
 $ READMIT.DX.CLASF    : Factor w/ 195 levels "ABDOMINAL ANEURYSM WITHOUT MENTION OF RUPTURE",..: 126 125 189 117 16 116 51 15 126 161 ...
 $ READMIT.ADMITTING.DR: Factor w/ 59 levels (intentionally blank)
 $ READMIT.ATTENDING.DR: Factor w/ 59 levels (intentionally blank)
 $ READMIT.HOSP.SVC    : Factor w/ 8 levels "CCU","MED","MIC",..: 2 2 2 5 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

From that data there are only two (2) `READMIT.SOURCE` ID'S that I am interested in, those being `"Emergency Unit"` and `"Transfer from Long Term Care"`, the reason being is that out of 798 observations these two account for 791 of them.

At first I tried `subset()` which was a no beuno. So now I have done the following:

```
er <- data.frame(radata[radata$READMIT.SOURCE == "Emergency Unit",])
lt <- data.frame(radata[radata$READMIT.SOURCE == "Transfer from Long Term Care",])
```

The above two lines gave me exactly what I need. My question is now, how do I make a new `data.frame` that will encompass both of the newly created? The structure of `er` and `lt` are exactly the same as what is shown above.

Thank you,

Comment: `radata[radata$READMIT.SOURCE %in% c("Emergency Unit", "Transfer from Long Term Care"),]`

Comment: @Roland thank you, please post as answer and I'll accept when I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read some more tutorials and introductions to R and pay special attention to subsetting. You are looking for `%in%`:

```
radata[radata$READMIT.SOURCE %in% c("Emergency Unit", "Transfer from Long Term Care"),]
```

Of course, you could also take your two data.frames and use `rbind` on them.